# What is Margot smoking / lighting up in the first shot?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-menu

In the very first shot you can see Margot lighting up something that appears to be a cigarette:

[image]

But then in the second shot she appears to be smoking a 'regular' cigarette:

[image]

You can notice that the first 'cigarette' is very different: it is dark and appears to have some sort of a label.

So, what is Margot lighting up in the first shot?

<sup>I grabbed some shots from the 4k version, cropped tighter & punched up a bit in Photoshop. It's still not really much clearer… but there certainly looks to be a shiny foil sticker in the first shot</sup>

[image]

[image]

Comment: In trying to punch this up in Pshop, what I had initially thought was a poorly-encoded dark bit in the middle of the label, even from the 4k still looks like an inky green stripe along the mid-point of this odd shiny sticker. In the wider shots later, she never fully lets go of the cigarette, so theoretically you only ever see one face of it. Odd shiny sticker could be hidden… but why would it be there in the first place...

Comment: Is it possible that they had to shoot multiple times and that they didn't have the original cigarette brand anymore and used whatever was available from a crew member? And that would be a very common brand with filter?

Comment: Is it possibly a cigar? The way the sticker seems to taper at the top and bottom makes it seem likely

Comment: It possibly comes down to 'who can identify this logo?' - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byr77.jpg - I can't. Never seen anything even vaguely similar on a cigarette, whether it's actually shiny or not.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I think it might be a Don Benigno slim gauge cigar; https://benignocigars.com/our-cigars/ but I can't find a good enough shot from the film to work with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not Margot in the first shot. Its stock footage. Whoever is in the stock footage does appear to be smoking the camel cigar noted in the [other answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/119418/9770).

> Filmmaker: Now that we’ve talked about the ending, let’s circle back
> to the beginning, The first shot is a close-up of Anya Taylor-Joy
> lighting a cigarette, which we later learn is a big foodie faux pas
> because it affects your sense of taste.
>
> Deming: That is a stock shot.

https://filmmakermagazine.com/118133-interview-cinematographer-peter-deming-the-menu/#.ZSm7xHbMKUk

https://twitter.com/ponysmasher/status/1622692875573297153

Comment: I love how he says *"There are some technical issues with the shot itself, which I won’t bring up, but no one notices it. "* … well - someone noticed it ;)

Answer (score 8):

As a heavy smoker and collector (cigarettes & cigars) for decades (quit 7 years ago, yeah!), I've never seen (or heard of) *any* cigarette looking like that. So, I search and looked around to tune down my first idea.

The dark cigarette shown on your picture is *probably* not a regular cigarette, rather a "filtered small cigar / little cigar / cigarillo". Note that only cigarillo can have a band added to it.

[image: different kind of cigars]

Traditionally, cigars have this paper ring around them, with the brand/logo printed on it. There's no etiquette or clear-cut answer whether you're supposed to take it off or not, but some agreement upon the fact that it should be done after you lit the cigar, so that the heat helps detach it from its natural wrapper<sup>1</sup>. Why this information? Because Margot is just lighting it, and it seems logical to still have the ring on it.

If I had to make a choice between a backlit white-paper regular cigarette looking that dark and a filtered small cigar or cigarillo shot in the dark, I'd 100% go for the latter.

Now, I can't find any evidence as the ring and the brand aren't clearly seen. If I had to guess, I'd say that, like in many movies where people were smoking, there are differences between shootings of a scene. There can be as few as one shot but typically there are several. During that time, you consume as many cigarettes as needed, some aren't even the same lenght or brand from one point of view to another. And, sometimes, you're left with a funny trivia quizz question.

Here are some other pictures showing filtered small cigars. I find them very similar to the one Margot is smoking. Only the brand is missing.

[image: filtered small cigar]
[image: filtered small cigars]
[image: filtered small cigars]

---

After more in-depth search on the web, I found these tar-free, nicotin-free, whatever-illegal-stuff-free cigarettes. They *really* look like the ones Margot is lighting. In the movie, Margot is told that her smoking will affect her palate. Smoking can also kill you, doctors say. What if she was not *really* smoking tobacco? Looks like a vice, sounds like a vice... Isn't a vice! So, she can walk free at the end. Nothing is going to kill her...

[image: tobacco-free cigarette]

<sup>1. [cigar bands and when to take them off](https://www.jrcigars.com/blending-room/university/cigar-tips/cigar-etiquette-cigar-bands-and-when-to-take-them-off/)</sup>

Comment: Due to workplace safety regulations, the actual prop is almost certainly a mass-market herbal cigarette, or a herbal “makings” created by the property department.

Comment: idk how it works specifically around the laws, but you can actually smoke cigars on an indoor set, and you can sometimes get away with real cigarettes on an outdoor set [basically if no-one in proximity objects.]